# cp command to handle empty directories (resulting in diff file sizes)

Tags: linux, cp

I am trying to copy directories (& files) recursively from one directory to another.

I tried the following -

```
rsync -avz <source> <target>
cp -ruT <source> <taret>
```

Both were successful. but, when i try to compare the sizes using (`du -c`), the empty directories seem to have mismatch in size.

In target directory

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 abc devl 4096 Jun  9 01:25 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 abc devl 4096 Jul 20 07:46 ..
```

In source directory

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 prod ops  2 Jun  9 01:25 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 prod ops 36 Jul 20 07:46 ..
```

Is there a special way to handle this? `diff -qr` doesn't show any differences though.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are both folders on the same volume? If not chances are that the sector size for those volumes are different and in turn the inode sizes differ. In case of diff it's just looking at whenever or not the directory exists and if it contains the corresponding files. It's similar in how diff doesn't include permission differences because those might be pretty system specific.

A pretty comprehensive answer can be found here: [Why size reporting for directories is different than other files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234065/why-size-reporting-for-directories-is-different-than-other-files)